# Devise error - ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Got problem in devise logout while admin and user logged in same page

For example i logged as user in chrome browser and logged as admin in the same browser,when i logged out of admin session the user session is automatically logged out and redirect to sign in page. 
When i try to login as user it's successfully logged in and goes to the admin login page and try to log-in it shows -

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

Comment: Are you trying to say you can't log in as user and admin on different browsers at the same time ?

Comment: when admin and user log in  there is no problem, when i log out the admin or user the next is also logout automatically.

Comment: You can not create two login sessions for the same application in same browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. Just in case, I would like to share one solution I found. I got this idea after reading this issue in device repo: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3461

```
class Identities::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  rescue_from ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken, with: :force_log_out

  #...

  def force_log_out
    return unless params[:action] == 'destroy'

    puts "rescued ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken"
    puts "force log out and redirect back to '/'"
    sign_out_all_scopes
    redirect_to '/'
  end

  # ...
```

I do not know if this is the best solution. If anybody has other solutions, I would like to learn them.